# Invalid property value in IE web browser?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The CSS below throw out a warning(**in chrome it works well**): Invalid property value

```
#commentblock ol li {
    background: url(../img/comment-bottom.png) no-repeat scroll left 50px bottom
}
```

What's wrong in the CSS above? any help please!

**update:**

I modified the css as below, then it could display the background pic, but it's not what i want?

```
#commentblock ol li {
    background: url(../img/comment-bottom.png) no-repeat scroll left bottom
}
```

[image]

What should I do now? the pic in the red rectangle is #commentblock ol li.

Comment: Just to point it out, there's a semicolon missing at the end

Comment: The problem may be that you have conflicting backgrounds. Do you have a background at a higher level?

Comment: @MrAzulay: I add a semicolon, the question still remains.

Comment: @helloworld: please see my update above

Comment: @MrAzulay The semicolon at the end isn't necessary, because it is a property _separator_, not a property _terminator_. Leaving it out is not an error and does not cause any problems in any browser.

Comment: @MrLister That's why I didn't make it an answer, why would you leave it out though? But you're right, It's not necessarily "missing".

Answer (score 0):

The position can only have two values, one for horizontal and one for vertical. You have three: `left 50px bottom`. So which two of those three did you mean?

In your question you say you tried removing the `50px`, but my guess is you meant to remove the `left`.

```
#commentblock ol li {
   background: url(../img/comment-bottom.png) no-repeat scroll 50px bottom
}
```

(Can't illustrate with a fiddle, sorry, since I don't have your graphics.)